# EBS Won't Size Correctly Windows Instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, diskmanagement

My root volume won't expand to the size the EC2 console shows we've set the drive to.
The C:\ should be 1.5 TB but only shows as 50 GB. The option to expand the volume isn't present in the disk management.

seems that  drive C cannot be able to extend due to a partition recovery is in between drive C and the free space

Do I need to delete recovery partition or alternative solution is there . Could anyone guide me how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you work around it by creating another drive with the unused space? I have enlarged Windows EBS volumes in the past but I don't know if it had a recovery partition, it was a standard EC2 Windows instance created in about 2018.

Comment: Thanks Time, I don't want to delete System Recovery partition, is  there any alternative solution you suggest except using 3rd party tools like AOMEI Partition Assistant . to fixe the "Extend Volume Option Greyed Out"  issue .

Comment: I can't suggest anything else sorry. This is a Windows issue rather than an AWS issue, so you can search for generic solutions rather than AWS specific.